# C# WPF DataGrid Group view of related tables

Tags: c#, wpf, grouping, wpfdatagrid

I have my data arranged in two related tables (SQLite). Let's say table Families and People. Table structure looks like below.

```
CREATE TABLE families (
    FamilyID        INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    FamilyName      VARCHAR,
    FamilyPower     INTEGER,
    FamilyStatus    Boolean
); 

CREATE TABLE people (
    PersonID        INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    FamilyID        INTEGER      REFERENCES families (FamilyID),
    Name            Varchar,
    Age             INTEGER
);
```

I'd like to display data from this table in grouped DataGrid. I can arrange this data as a DataSet, or as a custom class'es Objects or a netsted Objects (people could be a list of objects of class Person inside of the Family object). But I'm not sure which option is the best.

The worst option (I think) is doing one DataTable containing joined tables like `SELECT * FROM families LEFT JOIN people ON families.FamilyID = people.PersonID`. But I may be wrong and this is actually the best option to achieve what i want.

What I want is to display grouped data with group header containing full info about family and all its member as a data rows. So it would looks like below:

```
PersonID | Name     | Age     |
FamilyID: 1   Name: Stark    Power: 10    Members: 3  Status: [x] <-- This is checkbox
  1      | Eddard   | 60      |
  2      | Robb     | 30      |
  3      | Arya     | 15      |
FamilyID: 2   Name: Lannister    Power: 15    Members: 4    Status: [x]
  4      | Cersei   | 30      |
  5      | Tyrion   | 35      |
  6      | Jaimie   | 30      |
  7      | Tywin    | 30      |
FamilyID: 1   Name: Targaryen    Power: 10    Members: 1    Status: [ ] 
  1      | Daenerys | 30      |
```

Is it even possible to achieve that? Please help me to choose best way to store data and solve how to bind and group it in the DataGrid?

Comment: Please see this example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d7cdd861-5ccb-4c60-9b3c-702aafdc449f/wpf-datagrid-masterdetail-showing-in-the-same-grid-like-treeview?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks for clue but I don't think row details will solve my problem. I need all the detail data to be expanded. It should looks exactly as I provide in my example.

Comment: You can set properties to have the child rows always expanded  <Expander IsExpanded="True"> you just need to play around with it a bit.